# bootstrap 4 h2 tag does not show header in a separate line

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4. When i write header with header tags (h1,h2,h3...), the header should display in a single line. what happens is the next content is getting displayed with the header tag without line break. what could be the reason?

I have make sure that the header tag close properly

```
<div class="row">    <h2>Expertise</h2>    <p>Php, html5, css3, wordpress, </p>    </div>
```

the expected output should be like above

but it display like below. everything comes in 1 line with different font size. expertise is bigger than rest content.

Expertise Php, html5, css3, wordpress,

Comment: add your code here

Comment: <div class="row">
  <h2 >Expertise</h2>
  <p>Php, html5, css3, wordpress,</p>
</div>

Comment: Put your code directly into `container`or add columns in the row. In Bootstrap rows are horizontal groups of columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add columns to add content with in row as follows

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2>Expertise</h2>
            <p>Php, html5, css3, wordpress, </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 4 Grid System Rules**

- Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns
- Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the class "row" which contains display:flex. If you want to use row, then apply css "flex-direction" : column.
It will bring h2 to next line.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="">
    <h2>Expertise</h2>
    <p>Php, html5, css3, wordpress, </p>
  </div>
</body>
```